# Node server in Angular Universal

Tags: node.js, angular-universal

Recently I started a project in **Angular Universal** with its corresponding server in **Node**.

I have this **server.ts**:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/ostiaputa/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 8555;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
     
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

I compiled it with the command **"npm run build: ssr"** and two folders, **server and browser**, were exported to the dist

Well, after I hosted it, for this I have Tomcat since my main backend is **spring that sends api rest to Angular Universal.**
In the angular root folder paste the browser and paste the server folder out of root.

[Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GpcC.png)

Once this is done, run the node server with the command **"pm2 start main.js"** and it runs perfectly

**What is the problem?**

**When executing the application it shows Angular and the requests come out perfectly but it does not use the ssr well, that is, it is as if the server was not available**
I think it is because I either have to run it on another web server or I have something wrong to refer that angle to the server, I don't know

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you configure tomcat to forward requests to nodejs?

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName localhost
      # ErrorLog "logs/nodejs-error.log"
      ProxyPreserveHost On
      ProxyPass /nodejs http://localhost:8555/
      ProxyPassReverse /nodejs http://localhost:8555/
</VirtualHost>

Comment: And you are accessing the website as `http://localhost/nodejs`? Any error in the console for the nidejs process?

Comment: no, its work fine :/